# jQuery : Get row by tr 'id'

Tags: jquery

Hey im trying to access a specific row. I have the id attr of the tr I wan't to get.

My table looks like this:

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr id="1" class="odd">
        <td class=" sorting_1">bla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" class="even">
        <td class=" sorting_1">hej</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4" class="odd row_selected">
        <td class=" sorting_1">sdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="8" class="even">
        <td class=" sorting_1">testgfdgvcxbvcbcv</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="9" class="odd">
        <td class=" sorting_1">testgfdgvcxbvcbcvfdgsgfdgdfs</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here i need to access 
But I can't figure out how to access this.

Comment: id's shouldn't start with a number...

Comment: Is this really the ID? IDs should be unique across the page.

Comment: @Th0rndike: in HTML5 an id may start with a number.

Comment: Closing as per your 'answer'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you should usually avoid having numeric-only id's (unless you are using 100% HTML5!). And you should *definately* make sure id's are unique on your page.

But you should be able to use jquery selector

```
$('#1')
```

Assuming you're not using HTML5, then you should change your markup to use a more standard ID:

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr id="row1" class="odd">
        <td class=" sorting_1">bla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3" class="even">
        <td class=" sorting_1">hej</td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

Then you would access a particular row using

```
$('#row1')
```

Comment: This assumes the asker's IDs are unique. Do you think this can be relied upon?

Comment: @JanDvorak - based on the markup I can see, yes. Im afraid my powers to see the rest of the OP's code via ESP is a bit limited ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve any element, where you have the ID, using

```
$("#ID")
```

So in your case it's

```
$("#1")
```

This will return you the jQuery Object of the underlying HTML element, in your case the tr element.

Comment: Im guessing because there is no element on the page with the id `ID` that we can see

Comment: or because the answer seems to criticise the asker

Comment: Possibly, but this is perhaps the simplest jQuery question, and can easily be answered using a getting started guide. Guess we'll never know